Is the following connected space path connected?
Let us consider the topological space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal O)$, with topology $\mathcal O:=\{A\subseteq\mathbb R:A\subseteq\mathbb Q\mbox{ or } \mathbb Q\subseteq A \}$, where $\mathbb Q$ is the set of rational numbers. It is easy to show that this space is a connected space, since for every pair of nonempty open subsets $U$ and $V$ satisfying $\mathbb R=U\cup V$, we must have $U\cap V\ne\emptyset$. On the other hand, i have no idea how to check if this space is a path connected space (i.e. checking that there is a path connecting every pair of points  $x,y\in\mathbb R$). The first idea was to check the mapping $t\mapsto t(x-y)+x$, but it is not a suitable candidate, since  it is not continuous. I feel that the class of continuous mappings from $[0,1]$ with the usual topology to $\mathbb R$ with the topology $\mathcal O$ is very confined, and that this is the key to prove (or disprove) the claim.

Bizarrely, I think the space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal O)$ is path-connected: If $r \in \mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q$ and $q\in \mathbb Q$. let $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be given by $\gamma(t)=q$ if $t<1$ and $\gamma(1)=r$. If $U$ is an open subset of $(\mathbb R,\mathcal O)$ then $\gamma^{-1}(U)$ is either
1). $\gamma^{-1}(U) = \emptyset$ if $\{q,r\}\cap U = \emptyset$,
2). $\gamma^{-1}(U) = [0,1)$ if $q\in U$ and $r \notin U$;
3). $\gamma^{-1}(U) = [0,1]$ if $r \in U$, since $x\in U$ implies $\mathbb Q \subseteq U$ because $r \notin \mathbb Q$.
It follows that the path component of $r$ contains all $q \in \mathbb Q$, and since this is true of all $r \in \mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q$, it follows that $(\mathbb R,\mathbb Q)$ is path connected: for example, if $q_1,q_2 \in \mathbb Q$ then there are paths from both $q_1$ and $q_2$ to $\sqrt{2}$, and hence a path from $q_1$ to $q_2$, and similarly if $r_1,r_2$ are irrational, there are paths from both $r_1$ and $r_2$ to $0$, and hence a path from $r_1$ to $r_1$.

Sounds right! Thank you very much!

What the argument is using (I think) is that if $q\in \mathbb Q$ is a rational number, then its closure $\overline{{q}}$ is ${q}\cup (\mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q)$ -- if $F$ is a closed set containing ${q}$, then $F^c$ does not contain all of $\mathbb Q$ and so must be a proper subset of $\mathbb Q$, whence $F$ contains all of $\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q$. The paths $\gamma$ show that limits in $(\mathbb R,\mathcal O)$ are spectacularly far from unique!

@Viki183 Please consider accepting this answer. This is particular will remove the question from the unanswered questions list.
